# What is the syntax for gdal_calc.py to return a certain value?

Tags: gdal, raster-calculator

I'm trying to return the values from a slope raster where the values = 0.

I am getting 'invalid syntax' returned. This is what I'm trying

```
gdal_calc.py -A slope.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A=0"
```

I'm trying gdal_calc.py because the internal QGIS calculator is only returning NaN values no matter what I do.

Comment: --calc="A=0" should return 1 for 0 and 0 for any other value, try --calc="A==0" as the logical (C like) test. Do you have any python ability? This wouldn't be too difficult to script as a python script using GDAL.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I'm pretty n00bish with python.

Comment: Perhaps compile that into your own words and self-answer your question. I'm pretty sure that the docs http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html are a bit hazy on the logic employed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shout-out to Michael Miles-Stimson for the solution.

```
gdal_calc.py -A slope.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A==0"
```

This produced essentially a binary raster from a slope raster where values were 0. gdal_calc.py was used because the raster was too large for the QGIS internal calculator (as far as I can tell).